# Habilitar boton al esribir en el EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio, botón, edittext

Es algo que creo es simple,pero no logro resolverlo, intento que cuando yo comience a introducir texto, el botón se habilite, apenas detecte texto dentro del EditText

```js
 EditText id_emp;
id_emp = findViewById(R.id.id_emp);
Button buttonOk = findViewById(R.id.ok);

 if (id_emp.length() > 0 ){
            buttonOk.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            buttonOk.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Comment: prueba con el evento del editext .addTextChangedListener , ese evento salta cuando se escribe o borra algo en el edittext y ya ahi decides si habilitar el boton o no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo una aproximación de como debería ser puede que haya algun error de compilación pero esta es la idea:

```
 EditText id_emp;
 Button buttonOk;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonOk = findViewById(R.id.ok);
    id_emp = findViewById(R.id.id_emp);
    id_emp .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if (s.toString().length() > 0 ){
              buttonOk.setEnabled(true);
           }else{
              buttonOk.setEnabled(false);
           }

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    });
}
```

}

Comment: gracias, me funciono muy bien, con las pruebas no me dio ninguno error

Comment: Perfecto! Hasta otra

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar el `addTextChangedListener` que ya tiene metodos definidos como el `onTextChanged` :

```
id_emp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int i1, int i2) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int before, int count) {
            if (count>0){ //count es cantidad de caracteres que tiene 
                buttonOk.setEnabled(true);
            }else{
                buttonOk.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente

Comment: Ok no olvides marcar la pregunta como respondida.. saludos!